# Postman Tabs Groupipng

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I wonder if there is any way or some add-on that will enable grouping tabs that are currently open in postman. Usually i've gotplenty of requests and would like to group them to make navigation easier, without need of saving them as collections.

Comment: you cannot create a  request without a collection , your question is not much clear

Comment: You can have lots of unsaved requests created without a collection 

Comment: @DannyDainton Thaks Danny i learned something new then , never though of clicking new tab icon :D thats cool

Comment: There isn't the ability to do this in the app but you can. Create a feature request on the GH Tracker. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues